# Part data and change in upper and lower case in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

The script below is converting this `KP 67962188CAB` to this: `Kp 67962188cab` .

```
SELECT       
    LOWER(GENERICFIELDS.GFIELD2) AS GFIELD2 ,
    CONVERT(varchar(5),ORDE_.DROPTIME,108)
FROM 
    Drama_
```

I need part of the data in UPPER and part in LOWER. It should read this:

```
KP 67962188cab
```

The `KP` part is in UPPER, but `cab` is in lower. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUBSTRING or LEFT and RIGHT to split your string into parts, that you can cast to upper/lower case respectively, and then concatenate back together.

For example, if the last 3 letters of a string should always be lowercase, and the rest uppercase, do this:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(MyField, LEN(MyField)-3)) + LOWER(RIGHT(MyField, 3)) AS MyField
FROM ...
```

For example, this will convert "aBcDe12345fGh" to "ABCDE12345fgh"